# What's the theme here? (#3)

Tags: wordplay, rebus

Here's another group of pictures with a common theme:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]

Comment: #5 - oh dear. <blush>! :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Much of this answer came from [Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62165) - go upvote that answer!

---

**Theme**

> **Movie Directors**, found by [Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62165)

#1

> The notes that follow "do" are "re" and "me" → **Sam Raimi**

#2

> Pole and ski → **Roman Polanski**      solved by [Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62165)

#3

> Translates roughly to "Score, says he" → **Martin Scorsese**      solved by [Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62165)

#4

> An iceberg's spiel → **Steven Spielberg**      solved by [Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62165)

#5

> <strike>[Hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitch_(film)) Cock → **Alfred Hitchcock**</strike>
>  Co-Hen brothers → **Coen brothers**      solved by [Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62165)

#6

> ( Tare and tea ) No → **Quentin Tarantino**

Comment: I think I have a better fit for #5 now.  Other than that, I think we have it.  Nice job on 6 - I had no idea but it fits perfectly.

Comment: Yeah I think you're probably right on #5.  Nicely done!

Comment: Valid thought on #5, but (of course) @Pugmonkey was right. +1 for both of you.

Answer (score 9):

The theme is:

> Movie Directors

2.

> Roman Polanski => Pole - and - ski

3.

> Martin Scorsese => Score - says - he

4.

> Steven Spielberg => Spiel - Berg

5.

> The Coen "Co-hen" Brothers

Comment: Write `$\to$` / `$\rightarrow$` / `$\Rightarrow$` / `$\implies$` to generate the following arrow notations, respectively. $$\to\text{ / }\rightarrow\text{ / }\Rightarrow\text{ / }\implies$$

Answer (score 3):

Partial attempt, I think it might be the wrong direction though:

Theme:

> Fruitlessness?

1:

> No do -- Song should be "Do, a deer", but replaces the note "Do" with "Sam"

2:

> No go -- Not going anywhere without poles?

3:

> No dice -- There is no caption/bubble indicating the man said "Goal", entonces él no dice "Goal"?

4:

> No shot -- The bubble speaks of a shot in/of NYC, yet the image is of an iceberg

5:

> No luck -- One of the chickens is not going to "get lucky"?

6:

> No way -- The image crosses out the weighing of tea, "no weigh" -> "no way"

Comment: Entertaining, but "no right." :)

Answer (score 1):

The theme is:

> Words that end with an "*oh*" sound perhaps?

1.

> **Doe** (Female deer=Doe; Do=A deer, a female deer...)

2.

> **know** (I'm confident = I know ?!?)

3.

> **go** (Goal, he says and the announcers pronounces it as GOOOO...)

4.

> 

5.

> 

6.

> **No** (No tea and no weighting machine? => No waiting?!? (weight + tea)

Comment: Printer? Also for #1 you don't mention Sam