# What's the Theme Here? (#5)

Tags: visual, knowledge

Here's the fifth installment.

[image] [image]
[image] [image]
[image] [image]
[image] [image]
[image] [image]

Comment: Not quite... congrats on 1,000 rep!

Comment: Hahah, thanks. You're nearly on 10,000 rep :)

Comment: @Chowzen What's the 7th object? Is it bread?

Comment: @LaschetJain There's bread *involved...* It's a partial sandwich.

Comment: I found the origin of the $7$th object, and turns out, there is a face in there (and not my eyes being all weird). Head to this link $\longrightarrow$ (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixQbCXLUUj8) and begin watching from $4$:$16$

Comment: @user477343 According to [this page](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/see-the-virgin-mary-on-toast-no-youre-not-crazy/): "This photo taken Nov. 16, 2004, shows a grilled cheese sandwich up for auction on eBay that allegedly bears the likeness of the Virgin Mary in the bread. An online casino won with a bid of $28,000."

Comment: @xhienne ...which would confirm El-Guest's guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Comprehensive Answer, awaiting verification of #3 and #10**

I think I can add a few more here and try to combine everything:

1:

> Jewel (@Quantum Twinkie)

2:

> P!nk (@Quantum Twinkie)

3:

> Cher (based on "share" as described by @kayzeroshort)

4:

> Prince (@Bass)

5:

> Eminem (@Quantum Twinkie)

6:

> Blac Chyna (*Chyna* was originally intended by @Chowzen)

7:

> Madonna (@Ian MacDonald)

8:

> Sting (@Bass)

9:

> Socrates (@Ian MacDonald)

10: Could this be

> Wale ("Whale" with something (ie. the h) removed/fixed?)

From @Chowzen's comments and @feelinferrety (thanks to both of you!), #10 is

> Moby

I had initially thought **(theme confirmed by @Chowzen)** the theme might have been

> People who go by one name only

based on @Quantum Twinkie's answers.

Comment: Your theme seems right. It would also help #7 rot13(Znqbaan) and #9 rot13(Fbpengrf = "fbpx-eng grrf").

Comment: Nobody tried doing [this](https://www.google.com/search?ei=ew5NW4j_GM_V5gLLha6YCw&q=Chyna&oq=Chyna&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1j0i131i67k1j0i7i30k1l6j0i273k1j0i131k1.18103.18821.0.19438.5.5.0.0.0.0.123.552.1j4.5.0..3..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.541...0i10i67k1j0i10k1j0i7i10i30k1j0i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.IhYkcGMwAc8)? Theme and other answers are right, We just need #3, #10 and a comprehensive answer now, right?

Comment: Oh wow I din't even think that they all had one name! +1 :D

Comment: Could #3 be [rot13](https://rot13.com/) (Pure, sbe "funer", v.r. havg bs n fgbpx)?

Comment: I like this answer -- just updated my answer to credit kayzeroshort for #3. @Chowzen, how does this look now?

Comment: I suppose your answer for 10 works, but wasn't there a famous *white* whale?

Comment: @El-Guest - it's straight-up "Moby". For the record, it's somewhat forced since "fixed" doesn't mean the removal of... that particular bit.

Answer (score 4):

**Partial Guess**

> <s>Are they singers?</s>

1

> [Jewel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewel_(singer))

2

> [P!nk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_(singer))

3

> 

4

> [Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_(musician)) which sounds like "prints"  (From Bass in comments)

5

> [Eminem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminem)

6

> 

7

> 

8

> [Sting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_(musician)) (From Bass in comments)

9

> 

10

> 

Comment: 4 could be prince, 8 sting

Comment: Edited, nice find!

Comment: The theme is *not* singers, but your guesses are correct.

Comment: 6 could be the [Country Brothers](https://www.allmusic.com/album/country-brothers-the-brother-bands-of-country-music-mw0000153660).

Comment: 9 has almost enough pixels to suggest ”Socrates”

Comment: @Bass why "almost?"

Comment: @Chowzen, on my laptop screen, before clicking to zoom in, the detail that suggests the middle portion of the word is less than 4mm in both height and width. In imperial units (if I remember my conversion charts correctly), its surface area is no more than 0.0291 postage stamps, so it's a bit difficult to tell for certain which rodent it is.

Comment: OIC. Good call; much better than "Socbeavertes." :)

Comment: 7 is "Madonna" which is any artistic portrayal of the Virgin Mary

Comment: 6 is Blac Chyna

Comment: 9 could be tupac "two for the price of one"

Comment: Two pack sock shirt = Tupac shokur

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit of a joke, but I believe the theme is...

> **Brothers**

---

1. > [The **Diamond** Brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Diamond_Brothers)
2. > Unsure about this one.
3. > The [**Warner** Brothers](https://www.warnerbros.com/studio/about-studio/company-history)
4. > [image: Black Hand Brothers] For [*Dark Souls*](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/dark-souls-trilogy-collection-announced-in-japan-i/1100-6456046/) fans! 
   >  
   >  But for a more serious approach, there are the ***Hand***${}$**some Brothers** and the ***Hand***${}$**street Brothers**, but they don't match the picture apart from how there are hands.
5. > M&Ms $\to$ chocolate $\to$ [competition with other chocolate companies](https://culinarylore.com/food-history:what-do-the-ms-in-m-and-m-stand-for/), including the [Cadbury Brothers](https://www.cadbury.co.uk/our-story?timeline=1847).
6. > The [**Country** Brothers](https://www.allmusic.com/album/country-brothers-the-brother-bands-of-country-music-mw0000153660).
7. > I am not sure, but I believe I do see [Marilyn Monroe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marilyn_Monroe) in there. 
   >  
   >  **Edit:** OP confirmed it is not her, so unsure.
8. > The [**Bees** Brothers](http://www.beesbros.com/) (which after checking out the link, you will see the motivation as to why the bee is looking for a sting).
9. > I found the **Foote Brothers** and some brothers associated with **foot**ball, but it did not match the slogan, so unsure.
10. > The children's book, [**Whale** Brother](https://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-8027-6804-9). The slogan perhaps refers to Omu, who is a boy in the book that wants to "search for his talents" (according to the link), so it could be associated with the book as some kind of metaphor, perhaps.

---

## This answer was proudly inspired by...

> [image: Chicken] <sub><sup>([Image Source](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62159/whats-the-theme-here-3))</sup></sub>

Comment: Was your guess inspired by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxbyq.png)? :)

Comment: @Chowzen how did you know? I saw that picture in one of your other theme puzzles ([#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62159/whats-the-theme-here-3)) :)